# common validation for numeric fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there a way to get the type of the field for validation in UI. Basically wanted to apply same validation for all numeric fields. I am doing validation in java script.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? What 'type' of field? Do you mean type="text" VS textarea, etc?

Comment: yes I am using Jquery, for type text.

Comment: function checkValue() {
 var abc = document.getElementById('abc').value;
 var xyz = document.getElementById('xyz').value;
 if(isNaN(abc) || isNaN(xyz)){
  alert("Enter a valid number");
  return false;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so do this (with jquery):

```
$('input[type=text]').change(function(){
   if(this.value == 'whatever'){
          //whatever you want
   }
   else {}
})
```

Comment: for textarea is it $('textarea').change(function(){})

Comment: @divya or just add text area to the selector, id this the answer you were looking for? if so, mark it as accepted

Comment: I have another question. I am applying for all the textboxes. Is there a way to check if the field type in database is numeric or varchar in front end . I am reusing the same creation code for all textboxes.

Comment: lol prob. make a another Q about and post some code along with it